# How can I understand paint colorant systems?

Tags: paint

I want to better understand how paints are tinted so I can define custom colors. So for example, Benjamin Moore has colors like 2123-50, 2123-60, 2123-70 etc, each a lighter shade than the other. The formula itself looks something like:

```
W1 x3 22
G1 x1  1
R1 x1  2
```

How can I decode these formulas so I can make my own?

Comment: Get the details of their system and then work to the standards matching the tolerances. Of course, their system may be "in-house" ie private so they won't give it to you...

Comment: They use a concentrated colorant  and I doubt that you would be able to get it..

Comment: Good paint stores should work with you to get the color you want, without you having to specify the formula

Answer (score 3):

I worked in the paint department of Home Depot way back when and I can tell you that their paint labels list the letter of the colorant in the first row followed by the ounces and fractions of an ounce of that color.

[image: HD Paint Label]

The current label above is newer than what I worked with, and the color names have changed, but that label says that quart of paint has 0 ounces and 126/384ths of an ounce of the DL color, 56/384ths of FL and 6/384ths of RUL.

The different brands format the information in different ways, but it's all going to come down to colorant and quantity.  If I had to guess, I would say that your label would have 3 ounces and 22/128ths of W1.  Of course you would have to ask what the fraction was because I made up 128th and have no idea what it really is.

You would also need to know the codes for all the colorants.  There's probably 8-10 different colorants - it's not just primary colors.

Comment: Interesting sherwin williams seems to use drops.  So a B2 is 2 drops of black per gallon.  I used to deal with a different paint store and they had L2 being 2 drops of black per gallon.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger because there's more than one pigment system. Not least, *as-pumped* pigments are an emulsion of a solid pigment and liquid diluent.  The diluent must be compatible with the paint, so a pigment diluent for latex won't play nice with LPU paint.